# Scrolling Menu When Vertically Overflows

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hamburger-menu

I'm attempting to make this hamburger menu (visible when the page width is less than 865px) scroll to show whatever overflows the VH on screens not tall enough to display the whole menu at once. From my understanding by setting a fixed height to the dropdown section itself, something like `calc(100vh - *header-strip-height*)` combined with `overflow-y: scroll;` applied to `#header_menus` should work, however, because the `#header_menus` div is a child element of the top strip, and the top strip has a defined height, setting `overflow-y: scroll;` seems to force the dropdown segment to only take up the VH of the strip menu, and scrolls within the confines of the strip menu, instead of taking up the entire right side of the site, of all the solutions I've tried, I have yet to arrive at something that does not interfere with the placement of the body relative to the header, which is represented in the codepen by a placekitten image.

Looking for suggestions on how to allow the dropdown hamburger menu to scroll when it vertically overflows, without breaking the header layout in a way that interferes with the body in any way, ideas?

https://codepen.io/roomwillow/pen/BaWQoVJ

Answer (score 1):

The issue caused by the fixed height set on your navigation.

In order to handle this you can set an `absolute` position on the menu,
when the viewport is under 865px.

As such:

```
#header_menus {
    background-color: black;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100vh - 5.5rem);
    top: 5.5rem;
    right: 0;
}
```

Do make sure to add relative to the parent so it doesn't mess up the page:

```
#header_right_section {
    position: relative;
}
```

This will make it work.
https://jsfiddle.net/5zjw1b6h/